# Newtonsoft.Json empty object after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize JSON from a url using the following code. I'm getting an empty object even though I'm downloading a valid JSON string.

```
public static void tryjson() {
    string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.sofascore.com/football/livescore/json");
    SportItem sportItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SportItem>(json);
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Sport {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class Tournament2 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public int uniqueId { get; set; }
    public string uniqueName { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public List<object> mcc { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
}

public class Season {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
}

public class HomeScore {
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int period1 { get; set; }
    public int normaltime { get; set; }
    public int? aggregated { get; set; }
    public int? penalties { get; set; }
    public int? overtime { get; set; }
}

public class AwayScore {
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int period1 { get; set; }
    public int normaltime { get; set; }
    public int? aggregated { get; set; }
    public int? penalties { get; set; }
    public int? overtime { get; set; }
}

public class Status {
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Changes {
    public string changeDate { get; set; }
    public List<object> changes { get; set; }
    public int changeTimestamp { get; set; }
    public bool hasExpired { get; set; }
    public bool hasHomeChanges { get; set; }
    public bool hasAwayChanges { get; set; }
}

public class RoundInfo {
    public int round { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Sport2 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
}

public class HomeTeam {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public List<object> subTeams { get; set; }
}

public class AwayTeam {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public List<object> subTeams { get; set; }
}

public class Odds {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double odds1 { get; set; }
    public double oddsX { get; set; }
    public double odds2 { get; set; }
    public double odds1X { get; set; }
    public double oddsX2 { get; set; }
    public double odds12 { get; set; }
    public double liveOdds1 { get; set; }
    public double liveOddsX { get; set; }
    public double liveOdds2 { get; set; }
    public double liveOdds1X { get; set; }
    public double liveOddsX2 { get; set; }
    public double liveOdds12 { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOdds1 { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOddsX { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOdds2 { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOdds1X { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOddsX2 { get; set; }
    public string fractionalOdds12 { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOdds1 { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOddsX { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOdds2 { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOdds1X { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOddsX2 { get; set; }
    public string liveFractionalOdds12 { get; set; }
    public string americanOdds1 { get; set; }
    public string americanOddsX { get; set; }
    public string americanOdds2 { get; set; }
    public string americanOdds1X { get; set; }
    public string americanOddsX2 { get; set; }
    public string americanOdds12 { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOdds1 { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOddsX { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOdds2 { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOdds1X { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOddsX2 { get; set; }
    public string liveAmericanOdds12 { get; set; }
    public int odds1Change { get; set; }
    public int oddsXChange { get; set; }
    public int odds2Change { get; set; }
    public int odds1XChange { get; set; }
    public int oddsX2Change { get; set; }
    public int odds12Change { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsId1 { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsIdX { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsId2 { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsId1X { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsIdX2 { get; set; }
    public string bet365OddsId12 { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLink1 { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLinkX { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLink2 { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLink1X { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLinkX2 { get; set; }
    public string betSlipLink12 { get; set; }
    public bool liveOddsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool liveDoubleChanceOddsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class Event {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string customId { get; set; }
    public HomeScore homeScore { get; set; }
    public AwayScore awayScore { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public int winnerCode { get; set; }
    public Changes changes { get; set; }
    public RoundInfo roundInfo { get; set; }
    public Sport2 sport { get; set; }
    public HomeTeam homeTeam { get; set; }
    public AwayTeam awayTeam { get; set; }
    public Odds odds { get; set; }
    public bool hasHighlights { get; set; }
    public bool hasHighlightsStream { get; set; }
    public bool hasEventPlayerStatistics { get; set; }
    public bool hasEventPlayerHeatMap { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public int homeRedCards { get; set; }
    public int awayRedCards { get; set; }
    public string statusDescription { get; set; }
    public bool hasLiveForm { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
    public string formatedStartDate { get; set; }
    public int startTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public bool hasLineupsList { get; set; }
    public bool hasOdds { get; set; }
    public bool hasLiveOdds { get; set; }
    public bool hasFirstToServe { get; set; }
    public bool hasDraw { get; set; }
    public bool isSyncable { get; set; }
    public int? aggregatedWinnerCode { get; set; }
}

public class Tournament {
    public Tournament2 tournament { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public Season season { get; set; }
    public bool hasEventPlayerStatistics { get; set; }
    public bool hasEventPlayerHeatMap { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

public class SportItem {
    public Sport sport { get; set; }
    public int rows { get; set; }
    public List<Tournament> tournaments { get; set; }
}

public class Params {
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public object category { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public SportItem sportItem { get; set; }
    public Params @params { get; set; }
    public bool isShortDate { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like you used http://json2csharp.com/ .  `RootObject` is the **root** class.  try **`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);`**

Comment: worked ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, u) =>
{
    DownloadStringCompleted(s, u);
};
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.sofascore.com/football/livescore/json"));


private void DownloadStringCompleted(object s, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs u)
{
    try
    {
        var Item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(u.Result.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to parse into the json object first. Example:-

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultJson);
```